# Fixing a JavaScript conflict in Wordpress, help using wp_enqueue_script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I think (not 100% sure) that I am suffering from a javascript conflict.  I am using a pluggin to generate a countdown clock on my WordPress page, and I am using some simple custom made javascript with jQuery to make a div appear and dissapear on the page at certain points of scrolling.

To make the appearing / dissapearing div work correctly I added two javascript calls into my header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/test1.js"></script>
```

The first being the jquery library and the second being my custom script.  After adding these lines of code to the header, the countdown clock stopped working on my website.  Through a little debugging I have realized that it is the Google hosted script that is causing the clock not too work.

When I have the code for the Google hosted jquery library in my header I receive the following error: *Error = Object [object Object] has no method 'jCountdown'*

I believe the solution to this is using the wp_enqueue_script and wp_register_script in the functions.php file to add the two .js files I need, and removing the code from the header. However, I am un familiar with how these bits of code work and can not seem to figure it out.  Below is the code I believe needs to be used in the functions.php file, but I have been unsuccessful in making it work.

```
function notSureWhatGoesHere() {
        wp_register_script(notSureWhatGoesHere);
        wp_enqueue_script(notSureWhatGoesHere);
        }

        add_action(notSureWhatGoesHere);
```

And here is a link to my test webpage: http://jltest.biz/test-1

Thank you so much for your help and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Error = Object [object Object] has no method 'jCountdown'`

**Maybe** your plugin hasn't loaded properly...

Remove the jQuery you added `jQuery.1.10.2` so i am not supprised that it doesn't work..

PLUS - WordPress has already added a version of `jQuery.1.8.3`

Now, in your test file you have this

```
var startY = 840;
var stopY = 1900;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkY();
});

function checkY()
{
    console.log($(window).scrollTop()); 
    if($(window).scrollTop() > startY && $(window).scrollTop() <= stopY)
    {
        console.log("Show"); 

        $('.fixedDiv').fadeIn("slow"); 
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Hide"); 
        $('.fixedDiv').fadeOut();
    }
}

checkY();
```

Wordpress uses `jQuery.noConflict();` by default so you need to make sure you wrap your code in something like the following

```
(function( $ ) {

    // Code Here....

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear and have since modified my original post, this is the error that appears when I have the call for the Google hoste jquery library in my header.  When I remove that line of code from my header file, the pluggin works just fine.

Comment: I have tried that, (currently removed) however once that is removed my div that is meant to appear and disappear stops working.

Comment: Well, send a link to when you have removed it

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean. It is currently removed.